# C# LINQ NET 3.5 SP1: Using LINQ to group by two fields and assigning a correlative unique ID (integer number) to all member of the group

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2008, group-by, .net-3.5

I have a source list which each item is a class with public properties.

Item Class:

```
public class Item
{
   public DateTime Date
   {
     get;
     set;
   }
   public string ProviderID
   {
     get;
     set;
   }    
   public List<AnotherClass> listOfitems
   {
     get;       
     set;
   }
   public byte[] Img
   {
     get;
     set;
   }
   // Other properties

   public long GroupID
   {
     get;
     set;
   }
}
```

And the source list is for example:

```
List<Item> mySourceList;
```

So imagine mySourceList is as below at the beginning (represented here in tabular mode):

```
Date        | ProviderID   |  BillID  | QuantityToPay  | State    | GroupID
01/07/2015    9080AB          6453300      2100           Pending      0
20/01/2014    1080ZX          1200000      1500           Pending      0
01/07/2015    9080AB          6454000      1000           Pending      0
23/11/2016    6080AB          7853300     15000           Pending      0
02/10/2015    9080AB          6454100      2000           Pending      0
01/01/2017    2161DV          9200000       500           Pending      0
20/05/2017    8733ZZ          9800153     60000           Pending      0
01/01/2017    2161DV          9200001     21000           Pending      0
01/01/2017    2161DV          9200002     51700           Pending      0
20/05/2017    8733ZZ          9800154     90000           Pending      0
20/04/2017    8733ZZ          9800102     25000           Pending      0
20/06/2017    8733ZZ          9800200     90000           Pending      0
20/04/2017    8733ZZ          9800103     50000           Pending      0
```

Now using LINQ I want to obtain another list, myDestList which is grouped by Provider and then by date fields and also sorted by Provider and then by Date.
Also I want to assign a correlative number (GroupID) to each group (Date,ProviderID) that contains more than 1 row (this number should be the same for all members of the same group). Groups that contains only 1 row, this correlative number will be always 0. For example, after processing above list I want to obtain below list myDestList:

```
Date        | ProviderID   |  BillID  | QuantityToPay  | State    | GroupID
20/01/2014    1080ZX          1200000      1500           Pending      0
01/01/2017    2161DV          9200000       500           Pending      1
01/01/2017    2161DV          9200001     21000           Pending      1
01/01/2017    2161DV          9200002     51700           Pending      1
23/11/2016    6110FB          7853300     15000           Pending      0
20/04/2017    8733ZZ          9800102     25000           Pending      2
20/04/2017    8733ZZ          9800103     50000           Pending      2
20/05/2017    8733ZZ          9800153     60000           Pending      3
20/05/2017    8733ZZ          9800154     90000           Pending      3
20/06/2017    8733ZZ          9800200     90000           Pending      0
01/07/2015    9080AB          6453300      2100           Pending      4
01/07/2015    9080AB          6454000      1000           Pending      4
02/10/2015    9080AB          6454100      2000           Pending      0
```

I am trying below (without assigning a correlative number to each group as I do not know how to do it):

```
List<Item> myDestList = mySourceList.GroupBy(x => new { x.ProviderID, x.Date }).Select(grp => grp.ToList<Item>()).ToList<Item>();
```

How can I do this using LINQ?

**ATTEMPT #1**:

Finally I have done below:

```
    var grp = mySourceList .GroupBy(e => new { e.ProviderID, e.Date });

    int groupId = 1;
    foreach (var group in grp)
    {
        int id = group.Count() > 1 ? groupId++ : 0;

        // Loop through each item within group
        foreach (var item in group)
            item.GroupID = id;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've assumed that you don't want to update your Items in place, but simply need to generate new items.  I also don't quite see where the other attributes or "AnotherClass" come in to the picture.  So here's some code that takes a cut down version of Item (just Date, ProviderID and GroupID) and gives you the result you need.
Note that the assigned GroupIDs are not sequential.

The cut down class:

```
public class Item
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string ProviderID { get; set; }
    public long GroupID { get ; set ; }
}
```

Populating "mySourceList" (admittedly a bit rough and ready on the date parsing):

```
        List<Item> mySourceList = new List<Item>()
        {
            new Item {Date=DateTime.Parse("01/07/2015"), ProviderID = "9080AB", GroupID = 0 },
            new Item {Date=DateTime.Parse("20/01/2014"), ProviderID = "1080ZX", GroupID = 0 },
            new Item {Date=DateTime.Parse("01/07/2015"), ProviderID = "9080AB", GroupID = 0 },
            new Item {Date=DateTime.Parse("23/11/2016"), ProviderID = "6080AB", GroupID = 0 },
            new Item {Date=DateTime.Parse("02/10/2015"), ProviderID = "9080AB", GroupID = 0 },
            new Item {Date=DateTime.Parse("01/01/2017"), ProviderID = "2161DV", GroupID = 0 },
            new Item {Date=DateTime.Parse("20/05/2017"), ProviderID = "8733ZZ", GroupID = 0 },
            new Item {Date=DateTime.Parse("01/01/2017"), ProviderID = "2161DV", GroupID = 0 },
            new Item {Date=DateTime.Parse("01/01/2017"), ProviderID = "2161DV", GroupID = 0 },
            new Item {Date=DateTime.Parse("20/05/2017"), ProviderID = "8733ZZ", GroupID = 0 },
            new Item {Date=DateTime.Parse("20/04/2017"), ProviderID = "8733ZZ", GroupID = 0 },
            new Item {Date=DateTime.Parse("20/06/2017"), ProviderID = "8733ZZ", GroupID = 0 },
            new Item {Date=DateTime.Parse("20/04/2017"), ProviderID = "8733ZZ", GroupID = 0 },
        };
```

The Linq:

```
        var myDestList = mySourceList.OrderBy(i => i.Date).ThenBy(i => i.ProviderID)
            .GroupBy(x => new {x.ProviderID, x.Date})
            .Select((grp, idx) => new {GroupId = idx+1, GroupCount = grp.Count(), Items = grp})
            .SelectMany(newgrp => newgrp.Items.DefaultIfEmpty(), (g, i) => new { Date=i.Date, ProviderID = i.ProviderID, GroupID = (g.GroupCount == 1 ? 0 : g.GroupId)})
            .OrderBy(i => i.Date).ThenBy(i=>i.ProviderID)
            .ToList();
```

and the results:

```
{ Date = 20/01/2014 00:00:00, ProviderID = 1080ZX, GroupID = 0 }
{ Date = 01/07/2015 00:00:00, ProviderID = 9080AB, GroupID = 2 }
{ Date = 01/07/2015 00:00:00, ProviderID = 9080AB, GroupID = 2 }
{ Date = 02/10/2015 00:00:00, ProviderID = 9080AB, GroupID = 0 }
{ Date = 23/11/2016 00:00:00, ProviderID = 6080AB, GroupID = 0 }
{ Date = 01/01/2017 00:00:00, ProviderID = 2161DV, GroupID = 5 }
{ Date = 01/01/2017 00:00:00, ProviderID = 2161DV, GroupID = 5 }
{ Date = 01/01/2017 00:00:00, ProviderID = 2161DV, GroupID = 5 }
{ Date = 20/04/2017 00:00:00, ProviderID = 8733ZZ, GroupID = 6 }
{ Date = 20/04/2017 00:00:00, ProviderID = 8733ZZ, GroupID = 6 }
{ Date = 20/05/2017 00:00:00, ProviderID = 8733ZZ, GroupID = 7 }
{ Date = 20/05/2017 00:00:00, ProviderID = 8733ZZ, GroupID = 7 }
{ Date = 20/06/2017 00:00:00, ProviderID = 8733ZZ, GroupID = 0 }
```